# How to get current URL, on CSS content, using react?

Tags: css, reactjs, url, google-api

So, I know you can do this if you are running on php, but what about react? is it possible?

I need exactly this, but using react.

```
.class {
content: url(https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=150x15&chl=http://<?=$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];?>&choe=UTF-8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article: https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822. Approach number four (Style components) Can be something that should allow you to create css rules in dynamic fashion.

```
const Div = styled.div`
  content: ${someVar}
 }
`;

const OutsetBox = () => (
  <Div>
    <p>Get started with styled-components </p>
  </Div>
);
```